# Google Chrome opens empty new window when clicking Django dev server link

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-chrome

I had a Django project running perfectly using Python 2.7. Now I switched to Python 3 and whenever I click the link shown when I start the Django development server, google chrome opens a new, empty window where previously it opened a new tab in the existing window (which also contained the web application I was trying to run).

I'm not sure this has anything to do with switching Python versions because I remember seeing this issue before when I wasn't doing anything with Python.

Does anybody have clue? It's probably something very simple.

Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is to do with how your web browser handles links that are clicked from a third party application, and not with programming.

Comment: That's the point, I didn't want to assume that it's a browser issue. You do apparently :) and you may be right so I'll look into that more closely. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using LoginRequieredMiddleware, browser shows a blank page

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I haven't explicitly changed anything in the Django middleware but I'll check if perhaps something is amiss there.